# trigger function before iframe is redirecting

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, xhtml

i have an iframe in my page ' and i want to trigger function as soon as the iframe is reloading a new page (before the iframe is getting loaded).

**I need to trigger the function before the iframe is redirecting to the new page.** (as soon as the user click on a link in the iframe.)

***the iframe is not located on my server.

is it possible? thank you.

## edit:

- onclick event - trigger when page fully loaded :: not effective in my case
- onload event - trigger when page fully loaded :: not effective in my case

Comment: Is the page loaded in the iframe located on your own server (i.e., it is a page you can modify the contents to)?

Comment: If you don't have control over the iframes' content I don't think this is possible for security issues.

Comment: @elclanrs i either can't know when the user is getting redirected in the iframe?

Comment: Interesting question, but probably no workaround if it's not on your server...

Answer (score 0):

You can try checking the iframe URL on intervals, maybe this works:

```
 var ifr = document.getElementById("myIframe");                   

 var PID = window.setInterval(function() {
     try {

         var ifrState = ifr.contentWindow.document.readyState; 
         console.log(ifrState);
         var loc = ifr.contentWindow.location.href;

         if(loc.indexOf("newURL") == 0) {
             window.clearInterval(PID);
             console.log("url changed --->" + loc);

             // some code here
        }           
    } catch(e) { }
}, 5000);
```